# SonarLint Eclipse Extension treats Java files in package src/company/projects/web... as test

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

I did install the SonarLint Plugin from Eclipse Workshop today. 
Unfortunately it does not find any Issues for my Java files.

After digging around I finally found the Console output which says this for like 1000 Files:

```
File 'src/company/project/web/domain/GenericTemplateRow.java' qualified as test by 'JavaProjectConfiguratorExtension'
```

All I could find about this was that files which are not in the package `src/main` are treated as test files...

Is there any way to change this rule?

Comment: Maybe in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Source_ the source folder has the subnode _Contains test sources_ set to _Yes_ instead of to _No_.

Comment: @howgler I will check it after Easter weekend and report back

Comment: this seems to do the trick